# Android Studio debugging button press - event not firing

Tags: java, android, xml, debugging

I've created this screen using the design mode screen design.

[image]

The XML for this is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ftpDetails">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/test"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="292dp"
        android:width="250dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="216dp"
        android:width="250dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtFolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:width="250dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtServer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:width="250dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:text="@string/ftp_folder"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:text="@string/ftp_server"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/login_credentials"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/save"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This question is based around the bottom part of the XML, with the button btnSave.

In my Java class for this activity, I have tried to create an `onClickListener` like so

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ftpDetails extends AppCompatActivity{
private TextView txtServer;
private TextView txtFolder;
private TextView txtUsername;
private TextView txtPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ftp_details);
    setTitle(R.string.ftpTitle);

    txtServer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtServer);
    txtFolder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFolder);
    txtUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    txtPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(null);

    // Check that all text boxes have a value in them
    if (txtServer.getText().length() == 0)
    {
        // MESSAGE BOX
        AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        msg.setTitle("Enter Server");
        msg.setMessage("Please enter a server address.");
        msg.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Leave this blank, this will mean nothing happens, the msg just disappears
            }
        });
    }

    if (txtFolder.getText().length() == 0)
    {
        // MESSAGE BOX
        AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        msg.setTitle("Enter Folder");
        msg.setMessage("Please enter a folder to use.");
        msg.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Leave this blank, this will mean nothing happens, the msg just disappears
            }
        });
    }

    if (txtUsername.getText().length() == 0)
    {
        // MESSAGE BOX
        AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        msg.setTitle("Enter Username");
        msg.setMessage("Please enter your username.");
        msg.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Leave this blank, this will mean nothing happens, the msg just disappears
            }
        });
    }

    if (txtPassword.getText().length() == 0)
    {
        // MESSAGE BOX
        AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        msg.setTitle("Enter Server");
        msg.setMessage("Please enter a your password.");
        msg.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Leave this blank, this will mean nothing happens, the msg just disappears
            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

I have breakpoints on the lines

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(null);
```

and

```
if (txtServer.getText().length() == 0)
```

However, when I debug the app (Shift + F9) to my connected device (OnePlus 6T), none of the breakpoints are hit. Also, when I press the button and the textboxes are blank, the message alerts are not displayed.

Have I done something wrong? I've tried using the XML `onClick:` attribute but had the same result, as well as setting the same attribute in design mode, but again there was no change.

**EDIT**

Following the suggestions in the answers, I currently have this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ftp_details);
    setTitle(R.string.ftpTitle);

    txtServer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtServer);
    txtFolder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFolder);
    txtUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    txtPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

    findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(btnSaveListener);
}

private View.OnClickListener btnSaveListener =new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // my code in here
        }
    }
```

But still I get no result.

**EDIT 2**

After further investigation, when I press the button, the logcat window displays the following information

> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.866 28031-28031/com.example.my_test_app W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:425186): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=22761 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c129,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.875 28031-28057/com.example.my_test_app E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.886 28031-28057/com.example.my_test_app E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.876 28031-28031/com.example.my_test_app W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:425187): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=22761 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c129,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.896 28031-28031/com.example.my_test_app W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:425188): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=22761 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c129,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.903 28031-28057/com.example.my_test_app E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.916 28031-28031/com.example.my_test_app W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:425189): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=22761 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c129,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.923 28031-28057/com.example.my_test_app E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.942 28031-28057/com.example.my_test_app E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.926 28031-28031/com.example.my_test_app W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:425190): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=22761 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c129,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:57.954 28031-28057/com.example.my_test_app E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
>
> --------- beginning of system
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:58.237 28031-28057/com.example.my_test_app I/chatty: uid=10129(com.example.my_test_app) RenderThread identical 17 lines
>
> 2019-04-24 14:25:58.252 28031-28057/com.example.my_test_app E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"

Comment: you know that `setOnCickListener(null)` clears the listener? so, obviously after click there will be no action ...

Comment: also `if (txtServer.getText().length() == 0)` inside `onCreate` doesn't make sens ... it shold be rather inside listener `onClick` implementation

Comment: AFTER EDIT: your listener implementation is not inside the onCreate. move all your code there.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Moved 'private View.onClickListenener..` inside the `protected void onCreate` and it says "Modifier 'private' not allowed here"

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I've added the logcat output - does that offer any insight?

Comment: that error seems very specific to One plus6 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it wasn't an issue with how I was setting my listenener.

Changing the activity call from my `MainActivity` startup class to `StartActivity` meant that the `OnCreate` code was called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`.setOnClickListener(null)` won't assign any `OnClickListener`; so how are you going to debug that event? and that `.getText().length()` probably should be `.getText().toString().length()` ... so that the condition could be met.

Comment: *and that .getText().length() probably should be .getText().toString().length()* well, there should be not differences ...

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the listener correctly. Add the following code:

```
Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //add your conditions here
    }
```

Comment: Still no change here

Comment: @David Have you removed the null listener (findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(null);) and then added the above code inside onCreate?

Comment: Yep, all I have is the `super.onCreate`, `setContextView`, `setTitle`, the TextView declarations and then `findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(btnSaveListener);`

Comment: @David remove the last line you mention in your comment where you set a different listener. Essentially it's a different way of setting the same listener, but as you having is missing some code. All the answers here are pretty much correct but have different phrasing. make sure you stick to one, and it should work!

Comment: Sorry, I explained that badly. See my edit for what I currently have. I've also tried your method but it didn't change the result

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

`findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(null);`

into

`findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(btnSaveListener);`

and remove the followings lines from the `onCreate` method.

Then create `btnSaveListener` as follow:

```java
private View.OnClickListener btnSaveListener =new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // here goes all the code belove the line you change in the method `onCreate`
   }
};
```

Comment: I've changed the `findViewById` line as you suggested and took the rest of the following code out of the `onCreate` method. I the created the `private View.OnClickListenener...` and put my if statements in there. Still getting no result or debugging when pressing the button, though

Comment: move the declaration of the listener above the `onCreate` method

Comment: Hi Luca, I've edited the question with more information

Comment: Try to write this inside the `onClick` method: `Toast.makeText(ftpDetails.this, "try", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()` and check if you see something

Comment: I don't - I think it's a device issue, rather than a code issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192326/discussion-between-luca-nicoletti-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

why are you using click listener like this: `findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(null);`

do this instead:

```java
findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //put all your textView logic here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button click listener implementation is wrong, try like this:

```
 findViewById(R.id.action_ask).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Check that all text boxes have a value in them
                if (txtServer.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    // MESSAGE BOX
                    AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    msg.setTitle("Enter Server");
                    msg.setMessage("Please enter a server address.");
                    msg.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Leave this blank, this will mean nothing happens, the msg just disappears
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (txtFolder.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    // MESSAGE BOX
                    AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    msg.setTitle("Enter Folder");
                    msg.setMessage("Please enter a folder to use.");
                    msg.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Leave this blank, this will mean nothing happens, the msg just disappears
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (txtUsername.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    // MESSAGE BOX
                    AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    msg.setTitle("Enter Username");
                    msg.setMessage("Please enter your username.");
                    msg.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Leave this blank, this will mean nothing happens, the msg just disappears
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (txtPassword.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    // MESSAGE BOX
                    AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    msg.setTitle("Enter Server");
                    msg.setMessage("Please enter a your password.");
                    msg.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Leave this blank, this will mean nothing happens, the msg just disappears
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```